# Can I use a jigsaw to cut fence rails?

Tags: fence, saw, circular-saw

I'm looking for a saw to complete my fencing project.  I was using a circular saw to cut the fence rails but it went for a walk, if you know what I mean.

I'm now wondering if a jigsaw would be a worth getting instead of another circular saw because I have more uses around the house for a jigsaw than a circular saw.  However right now I need the saw to cut fence rails in half so I can finish my fence. These are 50x100mm SG8 KD treated pine and possibly laminated fence posts (112x112mm), although its fine if it can't do the posts.

I have found a number of jigsaws that claim to cut up to 80mm and one, a bosch, even up to 140mm.  I need the cuts to be flush and straight so my primary concern at is that the jigsaw blade will flex giving an uneven cut across my wood.

In saying that I have read the jigsaws can give really straight accurate cuts even in this wood or I'm a little confused.

Buy choosing a good quality saw and the right blade can I use a jigsaw for this purpose with results similar to that of a circular saw or even a mitre saw?

What should I be looking for in a jigsaw to meet my needs? or can I simply not use a jigsaw for this purpose?

Comment: Buy both, if you only buy one buy a circular saw. Jigsaws are best for cutting curves in sheet, even with a guide or fence my experience with a cheap jigsaw is it won't cut straight.

Comment: I'm a very experienced carpenter and woodworker, and I almost never reach for a jigsaw. The blades bend enough that most cuts end up out of square. I use them for thin stock only. If I need to finish an inside corner, I use a handsaw or a reciprocating saw, both of which have much stiffer blades.

Comment: To clarify, get yourself a good circular saw, which will do 95% of what you'd be stuck doing with a jigsaw, and much faster and cleaner. I'm partial to Makita--compact chassis, very smooth motors, excellent durability.

Comment: Agree with the comments above, except to say that you could be strategic and put the terrible jigsaw cuts on the posts in the ground. Or just get a half-decent handsaw (Japanese or traditional) to do nice cuts on the larger stock.

Comment: Hi Isherwood.  You mentioned a reciprocating saw.  Would that cut my rails and possibly posts as straight and clean as a circular saw if using a guide? or is still a circular saw the better option?  To be honest i don't need a super fine cut just something that is good enough for a fence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I own a Bosch JS470E and love it. I've owned many over my 20+ years in construction. It has a setting that will direct air from the motor to the area you're cutting and keeps saw dust clear from the line you're following.

"Will the jigsaw do the job"? Yes, with a good blade and little force but the job will go slow and the cut won't be as clean as a circular saw would do. If you won't use a circular saw that often I would suggest getting an inexpensive one. Maybe even go Harbor Freight. Then you can put some money into a good jigsaw for other uses.

Comment: Sub Lidl for Harbor Freight to get an idea of the kind of quality the poster is talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Just get a nice, cheap cordless Li Ion Circular Saw and be satisfied. 5 1/2" blade will do.

Comment: "Cheap" and "nice cordless" tend to be antonyms in the tool world, especially with Lithium Ion batteries. I present you [cheap](http://www.harborfreight.com/power-tools/circular-saws/7-14-in-10-amp-circular-saw-69079.html), and even [cheap cordless (bare tool)](http://www.harborfreight.com/power-tools/circular-saws/18-volt-5-12-in-cordless-circular-saw-with-laser-guide-system-68849.html). However, most nice Li Ion circular saws start at $100-200 for the bare tool, or $200-300 for a kit.

Comment: This ain't too bad. http://www.amazon.com/Black-Decker-BDCCS20B-Lithium-Ion-Circular/dp/B00FRMSMRE/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1454603939&sr=8-1&keywords=5+1+2+circular+saw Add a battery and you're at $100. Used it and it's OK. Not as powerful as my corded 15amp 7 1/2" saw, but it's nice and handy.